# I have IE9 on Windows 7, need to check browser compatibility in older IE versions...

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, compatibility

I have windows 7 (64-bit) and just upgraded IE9 in my machine. I did some design in html, css and javascript and works all fine in IE9, chrome, firefox, opera but I have to check this in older versions of IE, that is possibly in IE8 and IE7. I tried to search to download IE8 but could not find it for Windows 7, 64-bit OS.

Is there any other solutions to check my html page in older versions of IE without installing IE8 and removing IE9 in my machine ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bunch of free virutal machines that have all the IE browsers from 6 to 9
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575

Here is the application to run those virtual machines... also free:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4580

Comment: thanks dude, but my company does not allow me to install virtual machines.

Comment: It's pretty ridiculous to think that your company will not give you the proper tools to do your job. Have you tried talking to your systems admins? These are licensed machines by Microsoft for developers not some torrent ISOs.

Comment: I would like to try virtual machines and will probably talk to system admins about that. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @hayden yes, I work primarily in linux at work and VirtualBox supports VHDs

Answer (score 1):

In IE, if you press F12 for Developer Tools and click the Browser Mode button you will see emulators for IE7 and IE8.

Comment: wow, Barry thanks a lot. It really helped me. Tons of thanks :-)

Comment: The emulator do not perfectly mimic IE7/8 and even introduce some new quirks, so it's fine for quick checks but I wouldn't recommend relying on them.

Comment: Hi OriginalSyn, you are right that my company should allow me to install the virtual machines and that would be great if I could do that. I will talk to my system admin about this. Thanks for your suggestions.